# Process exists with ExitCode 255

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

[IIS 7.5 / Windows 7 / Visual Studio 2012]

I am trying to have my MVC app run an external command line tool located on the same machine.

I gave execute permissions to IIS_USRS to the whole folder that contains the tool.

I invoke it with:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();  
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;  
startInfo.FileName = myPath;  
startInfo.Arguments = myArguments;  
PartialRunProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

No exceptions (path is right), but the process exists rightaway with ExitCode 255

I can execute the process manually.

What could be the cause ?

Comment: Arguments were not the issue here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exit code 255 sounds like a .NET exception within the tool (target application) you're running. You'll not be able to catch this exception in your code.

I would [register a debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed%28vs.71%29.aspx) for the target application to see what exception it throws:

1. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options`
2. Create a key with the name of the executable you're starting
3. Create a string called `Debugger`
4. Give it a value, e.g. `vsjitdebugger.exe` if it's a .NET application

This will start the debugger and you can catch exceptions.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what the problem was. When I looked for standard .NET ExitCode values I did not find anything helpful. Does anybody know of a reliable compete list ?

Comment: Another way to launch a debugger (though not applicable to this specific problem, but applicable to mine, which was the exit code 255 i got from my own program) is to fire up the yourprogram.exe manually (from the Debug folder in Visual Studio if you use that), and before the process exits with code 255 (you could for example put a Console.Read() right before the line which causes the error), go to `Task Manager -> Processes -> right-click yourprocess.exe and click Debug -> Attach Debugger`. This allowed me to get more detailed info.

Comment: @Matthias: if you have the source of the application, you could also add a try/catch block and then do a `Debug.Break()` in the catch part.