# Batch script through Jenkins pipelines fails with - script returned exit code 255

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In order to delete multiple matching folder, I've following command -

```
cd/d "C:\\Jenkins\\jobs\\Test\\htmlreports" && for /D /R  %i in (*109*)do rmdir /s /q "%~i"
```

If this command is executed from command prompt, it succeeds. However if same is executed with `bat` in Jenkins pipelines like -

```
script {
  bat 'cd/d "C:\\Jenkins\\jobs\\Test\\htmlreports" && for /D /R  %i in (*109*)do rmdir /s /q "%~i"'
}
```

it fails with error -

```
Error when executing always post condition:
hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 255
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.handleExit(DurableTaskStep.java:658)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.check(DurableTaskStep.java:604)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.run(DurableTaskStep.java:548)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Please help to understand what could be wrong here.

Comment: Have you tried with `%%i` and `%%~i` instead of `%i` and `%~i`, resp.?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [Process exists with ExitCode 255](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789351/process-exists-with-exitcode-255#23789722), can help with your question about 255 exit code.
At last, i don't know how exactly Jenkins works, i don't use they... But, if the command
`bat 'cd/d "C:\\Jenkins\\jobs\\Test\\htmlreports" && for /D /R  %i in (*109*)do rmdir /s /q "%~i"'` was a cmd call, like `cmd /c cd/d "C:\\Jenkins\\jobs\\Test\\htmlreports" && for /D /R  %i in (*109*)do rmdir /s /q "%~i"`, i may know what is wrong:
bat files can't store a single percent.
cmd /c argument dont know the diference between the code that you put on there and the "&", even if you use a double &, maybe you need to use the ^. The command, in batch script file will be:

```
cd/d "C:\\Jenkins\\jobs\\Test\\htmlreports" ^& for /D /R  %%i in (*109*) do rmdir /s /q "%~i
```

and you put the code "do" with the ")" sign, and maybe it can cause an error too in batch script files, but not in cmd.
For least, verify if your syntaxes of the for combinate with what you want.

I hope i helped you.